# How to model recursive data structures in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I have a tree data structure that I would like to return via a GraphQL API.

The structure is not particularly large (small enough not to be a problem to return it in one call).

The maximum depth of the structure is not set.

I have modeled the structure as something like:

```
type Tag{
    id: String!
    children: [Tag]
}
```

The problem appears when one wants to get the tags to an arbitrary depth.

To get all the children to (for example) level 3 one would write a query like:

`{
      tags { 
         id
         children {
              id
              children {
                  id
              }
         }
      }
   }`

Is there a way to write a query to return all the tags to an arbitrary depth?

If not what is the recommended way to model a structure like the one above in a GraphQL API.

Comment: The idea is to not need to get all nesting all at once, but only when needed. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32497759/recursive-data-components-later-fetches-throwing-an-error or https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/246. Both of them make entity Human (respective Babushka) which loads children when needed. With some stoping points.
(As it not fully answer "how to get tags to arbitrary depth", I am adding this only as comment)

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. Of course you can load a hierarchical data structure  in steps, and that would be the normal approach for any structure that is large enough. In my case however (having less than 100 nodes in all)  this would be overkill and would unnecessarily complicate my UI with callbacks for node expand operations.

Comment: Other posibilty is make server side controller https://github.com/thecodingmachine/graphql-controllers... or flatten the tree to have only parentId property. Either is nice and clean, but both should work... what do you think?

Comment: I really like the idea of flattening the whole result and reconstructing it on the client side. I think this would be the cleanest approach, and the one I will probably implement, thanks again.

Answer (score 43):

Some time ago I came up with another solution, which is the same approach like @WuDo suggested.

The idea is to flatten the tree on data level using IDs to reference them (each child with it's parent) and marking the roots of the tree, then on client side build up the tree again recursively.

This way you should not worry about limiting the depth of your query like in @samcorcos's answer.

schema:

```
type Query {
    tags: [Tag]
}

type Tag {
    id: ID!
    children: [ID]
    root: Boolean
}
```

response:

```
{ 
    "tags": [
        {"id": "1", "children": ["2"], "root": true}, 
        {"id": "2", "children": [], "root": false}
    ] 
}
```

client tree buildup:

```
import find from 'lodash/find';
import isArray from 'lodash/isArray';

const rootTags = [...tags.map(obj => ({...obj})).filter(tag => tag.root === true)];
const mapChildren = childId => {
    const tag = find(tags, tag => tag.id === childId) || null;

    if (isArray(tag.children) && tag.children.length > 0) {
        tag.children = tag.children.map(mapChildren).filter(tag => tag !== null);
    }
}
const tagTree = rootTags.map(tag => {
    tag.children = tag.children.map(mapChildren).filter(tag => tag !== null);
    return tag;
});
```

//  Update 2022-08-16 Fixed typo

Comment: By the way, instead of `root: Boolean`, you might as well use `parent: ID`. This conveys the same information (parent = null means root = true) but allows clients to navigate the structure by parent and/or by children as they see fit.

Comment: @Tobia yeah, you'd ideally have both I suppose. The only reason to have both would be for ordering. The alternative if you didn't have the children array would be to ensure that the flattened tree is always kept in the correct order for it to be reconstructed properly. Of course, manipulating a structure like that is trickier.

Comment: I really like this approach, but I can't get it to work: I think in the `const rootTags = ...` line, some brackets / braces were swapped somewhere around `{...obj)}`, but even when changing this, VS Code shows TypeScript warnings and errors, e.g. `'obj' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)` about the first `obj` in said line and `Cannot find name 'obj'.ts(2304)` about the second.
Any chance you dumb down that line ? Might become less elegant then, but probably more helpful for anyone trying to understand the code...

Comment: On second (or third) thought, the mapping doesn't even seem required: Assuming `tags` is an array of `Tag` objects, then `const rootTags = tags.filter(tag => tag.root === true);` should suffice.

Comment: @ssc fixed a typo, thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you're willing to give up on the type-safety and subfield querying that GraphQL provides along with the ability to cache and reference the objects by their IDs is to encode the data as JSON. The [gaphql-type-json](https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-scalars) package provides resolvers to make this easy. These are also included with permission by [graphql-scalars](https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-scalars) which contains a lot of other handy scalars.

I'm doing this for the hierarchical data that defines the controls for a dynamic form. In this case, there aren't any IDs to lose, so it's an easy win.